# Can you work on the expiry date of a Canadian Work Permit?

Tags: working-visas, canada, paperwork

If a Canadian work permit says "Valid until 17 MAR 2017" then when exactly does it expire?

If you work nights, does it expire at midnight at the start or at the end of that date?

Comment: Ask your employer how they log your hours/days. When I was working nights, the day you start working usually would count as the day of work. Eg. if I start working today March 17th 2017 11 PM and finish 7 AM in the morning, then my day would be logged as 8 hours on 17th March. But it might depend from employer to employer. So the best way is ask your employer.

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience, your Visa validity includes the date that it is listed for. So, your's is valid till 12 am of the 18th of March 2017